# What will be the input to Microsoft Bot when receiving email?

Tags: azure, bots

I have developed Microsoft Bot to receive and send emails. Bot is developed in visual studio and published to Azure and connected to Email channel. I want to know the sample input to BOT when new email will arrive.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: Yes , It seems it's a JSON data

Comment: Can you share more information? Show us your code, link to the docs you followed, etc.